# ORDER BY case when statement / Multiple

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I would like to add a clause in my request :

```
SELECT * FROM MV_immo 
WHERE bien != 'Autre' AND bien != 'Indifférent' 
ORDER BY case
    when vendue = 'AV' then 1
    when vendue = 'VPNA' then 2
    when vendue = 'EC' then 3
else 6 end, Id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

Now, I have a column "position" (int) and I want to keep the first order and add the ORDER "position" clause (something like this ...) :

```
SELECT * FROM MV_immo 
WHERE bien != 'Autre' AND bien != 'Indifférent' 
ORDER BY case
    when vendue = 'AV' AND position ASC then 1
    when vendue = 'VPNA' AND position ASC then 2
    when vendue = 'EC' AND position ASC then 3
else 6 end, Id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

OR maybe ...

```
SELECT * FROM MV_immo 
WHERE bien != 'Autre' AND bien != 'Indifférent' 
ORDER BY case
when vendue = 'AV', position ASC then 1
when vendue = 'VPNA', position ASC then 2
when vendue = 'EC', position ASC then 3
else 6 end, Id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

My goal is to keep the first order (ORDER BY vendue) and add a 2nd ORDER clause : position. 
 I need your help for this cause I'm starting php and it's not simple for me.
 How can I do that ?

Comment: Why inside the case expression? I think you just need to put "position" before Id: else 6 end, position ASC, Id DESC LIMIT 0,6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
ORDER BY (case when vendue = 'AV' then 1
               when vendue = 'VPNA' then 2
               when vendue = 'EC' then 3
               else 6
          end),
         position,
         Id DESC
```

You can shorten this if you like:

```
order by field(vendue, 'EC', 'VPNA', 'AV') desc, position, id
```

Note that the values are in *reverse* order in the `field()` call.